# How to upload multiple files with Filestack?

Tags: reactjs, filestack

I am using `filestack-react` package in my CRA app. I can't find any option to upload multiple files the same time. Documentation doesn't say much about it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this using a property called **actionOptions** within the React Filestack component. See reference here:
https://github.com/filestack/filestack-react (Scroll down to 'Props')

I have passed to this prop an object called "PickerOptions", which is setting the number of maximum files uploaded at once. By default the filepicker has this number set to 1, but you can change that using "maxFiles: *number*"

You can find available options for {PickerOptions} here:
https://filestack.github.io/filestack-js/interfaces/pickeroptions.html#maxfiles

So my code looks like this:

```
  const PickerOptions = {
    maxFiles: 15
  };

  <ReactFilestack
     apikey={FILESTACK_API_KEY}
     actionOptions={PickerOptions}
  />
```